# In Python, is there a way to create a function that will accept both an integer and/or string input?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Thanks for looking into my message, I am very new to Python and so I am stuck in a particular problem.  I am trying to create a function similar to roulette. The user can only input the following as a bet:

- strings “Odd” or “Even” and..
- integers 0-36

I have been trying to set up a conditional check in my function to make sure the player is inputting the correct bet but I can’t seem to create a proper working check.  Here is what I have so far…

```
def test(bet):
  if (bet == "Odd" or bet == "Even") or (bet >= 0 and bet <= 10):
    print("Let's Play")
  else:
    print("Must be Odd, Even or between 0 - 10")
    return 0
```

```
#returns “Let’s Play”
test("Odd")
#returns “Let’s Play”
test(5)
#returns “Must be Odd, Even or between 0-10”
test(-1)
```

Everything works fine except when I type to test a non-valid accepted string input (anything other than “Odd” or “Even”).

```
test(“lol”)
```

This is when I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 12, in <module>
    test("lol")
  File "script.py", line 6, in test
    if (bet == "Odd" or bet == "Even") or (bet >= 0 and bet <= 10):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am excited to further understand and expand my learning..Thank you!

Comment: check isinstance, then make your function act according to the data type passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that if the strings `'Odd'` or `'Even'` are matched, the `if` statement stops evaluating the rest of the conditions.  This is called short-circuiting, and is one of the efficiencies implemented in Python.

When a different string is passed, it fails the first 2 checks (both are False) and goes to the numeric checks.  This raises the error you are seeing: comparing a string to an integer.

You can either check the instance of the input to split the conditions into string and integer, or you can have a set of allowed inputs, and check if the input is in that set.

method 1:

```py
def test(bet):
    if isinstance(bet, str) and (bet == "Odd" or bet == "Even"):
        print("Let's Play")
    elif isintance(bet, int) and (bet >= 0 and bet <= 10):
        print("Let's Play")
    else:
        print("Must be Odd, Even or between 0 - 10")
        return 0
```

method 2:

```
def test(bet):
    allowed_bets = set(["Odd", "Even"] + list(range(11)))
    if bet in allowed_bets:
        print("Let's Play")
    else:
        print("Must be Odd, Even or between 0 - 10")
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest / minimal change would be to replace:

```
(bet >= 0 and bet <= 10)
```

with:

```
(isinstance(bet, int) bet >= 0 and bet <= 10)
```

or:

```
(isinstance(bet, int) and 0 <= bet <= 10)
```

That also excludes `float`s if that's what you presumably wanted.

The problem is when your `str` value fails the first two tests, it's a direct comparison less than / greater then of `str` to `int` is attempted... and you see the rest. The other way around you do not hit that problem, because you can compare `str` and `int` for equality (they are not equal).